# What to do when the potential supervisor does not respond after initial positive response?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I contacted to the potential supervisor and got his reply after 3 days, saying that he is available to be my supervisor. Then, I contacted him again whether he would like to have meeting with me (which is part of admission process) or proceed the formal application. Now after 1 week, I didn't receive any of his reply. Should I send follow up mail or call him?

Comment: I would go for a call. Maybe they are on a vacation or a lot of other emails piled up.

Comment: @Oleg your comment is an answer.

Comment: It was more a personal opinion, I did not feel it's general enough for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After waiting for on week, it seems reasonable to write another *friendly* reminder email to him. Calling might be an option but you may not succeed if he is currently out of office. Therefore I would rather write an email.

Comment: I would wait more than a week, depending upon the deadline.